# phpmyadmin http login blank page

Tags: phpmyadmin

When logging in to phpMyAdmin via the URL http://username:password@111.11.11.11/phpmyadmin/, a blank page appears on first try. User needs to click on the location bar and press Enter to make it work. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving MySQL credentials (username, password) on the phpMyAdmin URL is not supported.